# Avoid duplicate translations in @ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am creating an Angular app and I decided against using built-in i18n and instead use ngx-translate (mostly ease of setup/use).

I want the app to default to english and lazy load translations over HTTP if requested.

For example in the component's HTML I type:

```
<h1 translate>
    We build apps
</h1>
```

and provide e.g. a "de.json" file with the translation using the HttpTranslateLoader.

```
{
    "We build apps": "Wir bauen apps"
}
```

The problem I face is that I can successfully switch to the German locale but not back without providing another "en.json" with duplicate translations.

```
{
    "We build apps": "We build apps"
}
```

Is there any way to to have the app go back to English without having to duplicate all English translations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to PeS I was able to solve the issue, but only creating the handler was not enough.

I also had to add an empty `en.json` file with only `{}` as content, next to the other translations.

```
export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
    handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
        return params.key;
    }
}

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/locale/', '.json');
}

TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
            deps: [HttpClient],
        },
        missingTranslationHandler: {
            provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
            useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler,
        },
        useDefaultLang: false,
    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to create `MissingTranslationHandler` and just return the key.